# How to sense amplitute of sound through Audiorecorder?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, audio

I have created sample project and want to check if I can read the sound amplitude. So far I have started a service from main activity and in service class I have put some code to read sound amplitude. According to tutorial it should have worked but don't known why not working. Here is the code

```
 public class MyService extends Service {

        int sampleRate = 8000;
        AudioRecord audioRecord;
        int bufferSize;
        double lastLevel;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            Log.d("TAG", "oncreate called of service");

        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {

            super.onDestroy();
            Log.d("TAG", "oncDestroy called of service");

        }



        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

            Log.d("TAG", "onstart command  called of service");
            try {
                bufferSize = AudioRecord
                        .getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                        sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                android.util.Log.e("TrackingFlow", "Exception", e);
            }


            audioRecord.startRecording();

            if (lastLevel > 0 && lastLevel <= 50) {
                Log.d("TAG", "lastlevel is less then 50");
            } else if (lastLevel > 50 && lastLevel <= 100) {
                Log.d("TAG", "lastlevel is less then/equal 100");
            } else if (lastLevel > 100 && lastLevel <= 170) {
                Log.d("TAG", "lastlevel is less then/= 170");
            }
            if (lastLevel > 170) {
                Log.d("TAG", "lastlevel is greater then 170");
            }

            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

            return null;

        }

    }
```

[Here](http://www.doepiccoding.com/blog/?p=195) is the tutorial link. I am also not familiar with services, I hope my service class is exact the way it should be. I am able to get sense sound first time, but after on words it is not sense the rest of sound. Is my service class not correct? Or some wrong with the audioRecorder I can't figure out. I have debuged it too first time it work but after that not working.

Comment: and what exactly is not working???

Comment: my service class is called audiorecorder is also start but it cant sense ampplitute and none of log are called which i have created in onstartcommand founction..

Comment: you should step through your code with your debugger

Comment: @zerO i have edited my question after i debug i am able to sense sound first time but after that its not working.